# How to increment variable in template Angular?

Tags: angular

I have the following template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let documentsGroup of documents | groupBy: 'doctype'"><
   <tr *ngFor="let doc of documentsGroup.value; let i = index">{{num}</tr>
</ng-container>
```

I know that it is not good to call `{{num}}` in template, because it will be rendered each time.

**Component is:**

```
public t = 1;
public get num() {
    return this.t++;
}
```

So, how to create variable `num` in template and increment it like `{{num++}}`?

Comment: you have `let i = index` why wouldn't you render  just `{{i}}` or `{{1 + i}}`

Comment: Because it is groupped data using pipe: `groupBy: 'doctype'`

Comment: I have array of objects that I group by object property `type`. As result I get array of groups with elements inside as array. So array in array

Comment: and what do you want to be rendered? just numbers? if so - why would you need to group if you render just the same numbers?

Comment: Yes, I need to show numbers, for exmaple: `let groups = [{key: "title", value: [1,2,3]}, {key: "title 2", value: [4, 5]}]` So I need to get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, because I have 5 items in summary in two groups.

Comment: you will get exactly the same result if you just iterate over ungrouped array (with only one ngFor) and render the same thing

Comment: I know, but in first loop data is already groupped: `documents | groupBy: 'doctype'"`

Comment: so you don't need explicit "groups", you just need to items from one group be near each other in the resulting array?

Comment: I have 20 objects in array, it is plain array. I group each elements of array by property `type` of object. So, amount the same 20. But groopped in array. Arrar of arrays. So I need to show numbers of each elements: 1,2...20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a simple example.
But I recommend you use it in the component which change detection strategy changed to the `onPush`.

Here is the link to the stackblitz example.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-rad9zs?file=app%2Fapp.component.html